# GWT Compiler Error: Element 'extend-property' contains unexpected attribute 'fallback-value'

Tags: java, gwt, maven

When I'm trying to run my app on server I have the following errors:

```
Error:GWT Compiler: Element 'extend-property' beginning on line 27 contains unexpected attribute 'fallback-value'
Error:GWT Compiler: Failure while parsing XML
Error:GWT Compiler: at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.DefaultSchema.onUnexpectedAttribute(DefaultSchema.java:68)
Error:GWT Compiler: at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.Schema.onUnexpectedAttribute(Schema.java:80)
Error:GWT Compiler: at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:224)
Error:GWT Compiler: at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:506)
Error:GWT Compiler: at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
Error:GWT Compiler: at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1303)
Error:GWT Compiler: at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2717)
Error:GWT Compiler: at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
Error:GWT Compiler: at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
Error:GWT Compiler: at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
Error:GWT Compiler: at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
Error:GWT Compiler: at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
Error:GWT Compiler: at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
Error:GWT Compiler: at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
Error:GWT Compiler: at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:327)
Error:GWT Compiler: at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$100(ReflectiveParser.java:48)
Error:GWT Compiler: at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:398)
Error:GWT Compiler: at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:257)
Error:GWT Compiler: at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefSchema$BodySchema.__inherits_begin(ModuleDefSchema.java:354)
Error:GWT Compiler: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error:GWT Compiler: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error:GWT Compiler: at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error:GWT Compiler: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
Error:GWT Compiler: at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:223)
Error:GWT Compiler: at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:270)
Error:GWT Compiler: at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:766)
Error:GWT Compiler: at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader$1.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:169)
Error:GWT Compiler: at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:283)
Error:GWT Compiler: at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:141)
Error:GWT Compiler: at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:184)
Error:GWT Compiler: at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:152)
Error:GWT Compiler: at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:87)
Error:GWT Compiler: at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:81)
Error:GWT Compiler: at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:159)
Error:GWT Compiler: Unexpected error while processing XML
Error:GWT Compiler: at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:351)
Error:GWT Compiler: Unexpected exception while processing element 'inherits'
Error:GWT Compiler: at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.DefaultSchema.onHandlerException(DefaultSchema.java:56)
Error:GWT Compiler: at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.Schema.onHandlerException(Schema.java:66)
Error:GWT Compiler: at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:233)
```

I guess these all are caused by maven, so here is pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.messagedna.dlp</groupId>
  <artifactId>DLPServer</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>DLPServer</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
          <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.3</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
          <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.3</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.extjs</groupId>
          <artifactId>gxt</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
          <version>1.9</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
          <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
          <version>1.4.5</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.james</groupId>
          <artifactId>apache-mime4j</artifactId>
          <version>0.6.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
          <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
          <version>1.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>net.freeutils.jtnef</groupId>
          <artifactId>tnef</artifactId>
          <version>1.5.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.messagedna-archive.mimeparser</groupId>
          <artifactId>MimeParser</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
          <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
          <version>2.3</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.10</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
        <outputDirectory>war/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
              <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>1.2</version>
              <executions>
                  <execution>
                      <goals>
                          <goal>compile</goal>
                          <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                          <goal>test</goal>
                      </goals>
                  </execution>
              </executions>
              <configuration>
                  <runTarget>Main.html</runTarget>
                  <style>OBFUSCATED</style>
                  <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx1024m -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
                  <webappDirectory>war</webappDirectory>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>

          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.1.1</version>
              <configuration>
                  <webappDirectory>war</webappDirectory>
                  <warSourceExcludes>.gwt-tmp/**</warSourceExcludes>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

whenever I've trying to search in google I didn't figured out the solution, there were questions partly like this but they are without any solution.

So, please, have a look at this and I'll be very greatful if you can suggest any way to solve this problems.

Answer (score 2):

The error comming from the GWT compiler, it probably has nothing to do with maven, but rather with a GWT XML configuration file, such as an UIBinder file.

The message tells you that you used an attribute called "extend-property" at a place where it is not expected. So look for this attribute in your project. If it is in fact inside a UIBinder XML file, keep in mind that attribute names for XML elements must be the same as attribute names from the corresponding java classes (so probably no hyphens).

Comment: I understood you well enough, I can say that I've never used such attribute in my project at all.

Comment: Ok, can you try updrading GWT to version 2.5 in your POM?

Comment: Also the stack shows that the error occurs during computing the inheritance of a module. So check the GWT modules you are using in your project. Maybe one of these modules uses this attribute, which might me not implemented in your old GWT version. Which is why I suggested trying a newer version of GWT.

Comment: the problem was that It was gwt-user from gwt-sdk and another gwt-user added by dependencies

Comment: OK, i suggest you make your own answer and accept, so that people having the same problem can see it more easily.

Answer (score 1):

the problem was that It was gwt-user from gwt-sdk and another gwt-user added by dependencies